# Functional programming setters

Tags: scala, functional-programming, setter

How can I do a setter in functional programming like so? I would like to respect immutability and other functional programming principles.

```
private int age;

public void setAge(int age){

this.age=age;

}
```

Is that possible? If not, how can I represent the state (and its changes) of a program in a functional programming language?

Comment: You would create a new object which is otherwise identical except its age is set to the new age.

Comment: Please, read [that](http://dustinmartin.net/getters-and-setters-in-scala/) article.

Comment: Why the downvotes? "With mutable classes I'm using setters, what should I use with immutable classes?" - I guess it's a good question for a newbie in FP.

Comment: @senia: Agreed, and I'm not really sure what the article linked by Artsiom has to do with the question (not that it's bad—it's just not about immutable classes).

Answer (score 10):

In general you should create a new state instead of modifying the old one.

#### Copy

You could use `copy` method like this:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

val youngBob = Person("Bob", 15)
val bob = youngBob.copy(age = youngBob.age + 1)
// Person(Bob,16)
```

#### scalaz Lens

You could also use `Lens`:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

val ageLens = Lens.lensu[Person, Int]( (p, a) => p.copy(age = a), _.age )

val bob = ageLens.mod(_ + 1, youngBob)
// Person(Bob,16)
```

See [Learning scalaz/Lens](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Lens.html). There are also other implementations of `Lens`.

#### shapeless Lens

For instance you could use `shapeless` `Lens` that implemented using macros, so you don't have to create lens manually:

```
import shapeless._

val ageLens = Lens[Person] >> 1

val bob = ageLens.modify(youngBob)(_ + 1)
// Person(Bob,16)
```

See [examples on github](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/shapeless-2.0.0-M1/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/lenses.scala).

#### See also

There are a lot of `Lens` implementations. See [Boilerplate-free Functional Lenses for Scala](http://akisaarinen.fi/blog/2012/12/07/boilerplate-free-functional-lenses-for-scala/) and [Macrocosm](https://github.com/retronym/macrocosm).

Answer (score 1):

While it's practically an oxymoron to talk about an FP mutator, Scala (as a hybrid object-functional language) does have a syntax for creating mutators and mutator-like methods:

```
scala> class C1 { def x: Int = xx; def x_=(i: Int): Unit = xx = i; private var xx: Int = 0 }
defined class C1

scala> val c1 = new C1
c1: C1 = C1@1e818d28

scala> c1.x = 23
c1.x: Int = 23

scala> c1.x
res18: Int = 23
```

Naturally, as shown there's no point in this but whatever backs the named accessor and mutator need not be a simple field and the mutator may impose range constraints on the value or do some logging when the value is mutated, so it's a fairly general construct.

Note that you cannot have the  mutator alone. It has to have an accessor counterpart.

**Addendum**

Immutable w/ mutator w/o case class

```
scala> class C2(xInit: Int) { def this = this(0)
                              def x: Int = xx
                              def x_=(i: Int): C2 = new C2(i)
                              private var xx: Int = xInit
                            }

scala> val c2a = new C2()
c2a: C2 = C2@2f85040b

scala> val c2b = c2a.x = 23
c2b: C2 = C2@74f1bfa9

scala> c2a.x
res19: Int = 0

scala> c2b.x
res20: Int = 23
```